# Inconsistent behavior testing Taproot Workshop - Section: 0.2 Elliptic Curve Math

Tags: taproot, secp256k1

Workshop link: https://github.com/bitcoinops/taproot-workshop/

In the section `0.2.4 Programming Exercise: Distributivity of scalar operations`  we implement the following code:

```
a_key = ECKey().set(a)

b = random.randrange(1, SECP256K1_ORDER)
b_key = ECKey().set(b)

c = random.randrange(1, SECP256K1_ORDER)
c_key = ECKey().set(c)

# Left: Compute a - b as ints (modulo the sepc256k1 group order)
a_minus_b =  (a - b) % SECP256K1_ORDER# TODO: implement

# Left: Compute (a - b) * c as ints (modulo the sepc256k1 group order)
left =  (a_minus_b * c) % SECP256K1_ORDER# TODO: implement

# Right: Compute a * c - b * c as ECKeys
right = (a * c % SECP256K1_ORDER) - (b * c % SECP256K1_ORDER) # TODO: implement 
#if you dont modulo curve order in both parenthesis your number (probably) becomes too large for the curve
#therefore calling .secret on it will not work even if you cast it to ECKey Object (so the assertion cannot even happen in this case)
#you would only be able to call .secret on a value within the curve order

print("Left: {}".format(left))
print("Right: {}".format(right))


right = ECKey().set(right)
# Left/Right: Assert equality
assert left == right.secret
print("\nSuccess!")
```

Note that the lines with `#TODO: implement` are the only ones I have modified.

When trying this code block a few times I noticed that it fails occasionally with:

```
Left: 84229569338898829804715923445734053841060795723920762893503652295039608159004
Right: -31562519898417365618855061562953854011776768555154141489101510846478553335333
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 28
     26 right = ECKey().set(right)
     27 # Left/Right: Assert equality
---> 28 assert left == right.secret
     29 print("\nSuccess!")

AttributeError: 'ECKey' object has no attribute 'secret'
```

The attribute error suggests that the generated secret is outside the curve order and was not properly turned into the ECKey

But for at least 50% of the time it returns something like:

```
Left: 51082417157028894624564857296082907029625179491897309339882235219613900809295
Right: 51082417157028894624564857296082907029625179491897309339882235219613900809295

Success!
```

What is causing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `right` is calculated with `(a * c % SECP256K1_ORDER) - (b * c % SECP256K1_ORDER)`. There's no guarantee that one side of the `-` will always be bigger than the other side, so it's possible that `(b * c % SECP256K1_ORDER)` is bigger than `(a * c % SECP256K1_ORDER)` which results in `right` being a negative number. As a negative number, it cannot be a valid scalar, and so its `secret` is not set. Since all of the numbers are random, this happens with 50% probability.

To resolve this, you just need to handle the negatives correctly. A negative number in a prime is just its absolute value subtracted from the prime (`SECP256K1_ORDER`). How you achieve that is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: That makes tons of sense thank you for the clear explanation!